# How Can I Convert Bootstrap to older version?

Tags: html, css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

ı have created a div with using bootstrap 4.0 but i want to use that div in another page that is creating with bootstrap 3.7 so these two versions of bootstrap conflicts.How can i convert bootstrap 4.0 to bootstrap 3.7 without breaking down?

I have added code of my div with using bootstrap 4.0 and please help me to convert my div to bootstrap 3.7.

Thanks in advance.

```html
     <div id="divSignature" class="container" style="margin-top:10px;padding-top:10px; width:420px;height:250px;background-color:White;font-size:14px;">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-1">
                <img style="width: 140px" src="images/logo_signature.png"/>
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-11" style="margin-left: 15px">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-10">
                            <div class="container">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <h5>
                                  <b>   <asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server" style="font-family:'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif"></asp:Label> </b>
                                    </h5>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row" style="margin-top: -5px">
                                    <p class=".font-weight-normal">
                                        <asp:Label ID="lblTitle" runat="server" style="font-family:'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif"></asp:Label>                
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                                <hr style="margin-top: -10px;"/>
                                <div class="row" style="margin-top: -15px">
                                        <p>
                                            <strong>M&nbsp;:</strong><asp:Label ID="lblPhone" runat="server" style="font-family:'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif"></asp:Label>
                                        </p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row"  style="margin-top: -20px">
                                        <p>
                                            <strong>T&nbsp;&nbsp;: </strong><p style="font-family:'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif">  +00 00 00 00</p>
                                        </p>
                                    </div>

                                <div class="row"  style="margin-top: -20px">
                                        <p>
                                            <strong>E &nbsp;:&nbsp;</strong><asp:Label ID="lblEmail" runat="server" style="font-family:'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif"></asp:Label>
                                        </p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="row"  style="margin-top: -20px">
                                            <p>
                                                <strong>W:&nbsp;</strong><p style="font-family:'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif"> www.france.com</p>
                                            </p>
                                        </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
            
        </div>
        <div class="row" style="margin-top: 0px; margin-left: 1px;font-size:12px;">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-11" style="align-self: center;font-family:'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif" >
                               
                                France<br/>
                        </div>
                            
                        <div class="col-xs-1" style="margin-left: 15px;margin-bottom:10px;">
                                <img width="70" src="images/qr_code.png"/>    
                        </div>       
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row" style="margin-top: 0px; margin-left: 0px" >
                <img style="width: 400px" src="images/seritt.png"/>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Reference the [3.x docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/). There is nothing in your code that is specific to 3 or 4. `.row`, `.container`, and `.col-` are used in both versions.  `.col-xs-*` has changed simply to  `.col-*` in 4.x. Don't nest `container` inside `row`. And why are you using all the custom inline styles?

Answer (score 0):

Identify classes from your code that are not supported in previous version of bootstrap and replace them with different ones.

Answer (score 0):

your `HTML` is not good enough you are mixing `CSS` with `HTML,` and that is bad when someone wants to read your code.

- I don't see any class of `Bootstrap 4` on this `HTML` document.
- I can see some issues that you have in your `HTML,` for example you are working with multiple containers and that is not necessary, and it is not good practices. You are working with `col-xs-1` to set the with of an `img` and that is not the correct way.
- You are mixing multiple columns and rows, and that is not a right way to do it.

These changes can improve you code and make render faster and goodle will improve the rating. I removed the CSS I encourage you to create an external `CSS` file and write your `CCS` rules there.

```
<div id="divSignature" class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div>
          <img style="width: 140px" class='img-resposive' src="images/logo_signature.png"/>
      </div> 
      <div class="col-xs-11">
          <h5>
            <asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server"></asp:Label>
          </h5>
          <div class="row">
              <p>
                  <asp:Label ID="lblTitle" runat="server"></asp:Label>                
              </p>
          </div>
          <hr/>
          <div class="row">
              <p>
                  <strong>M&nbsp;:</strong><asp:Label ID="lblPhone" runat="server"></asp:Label>
              </p>
          </div>
          <div class="row"  style="margin-top: -20px">
              <p>
                  <strong>T&nbsp;&nbsp;: </strong><p>  +00 00 00 00</p>
              </p>
          </div> 
          <div class="row"  style="margin-top: -20px">
              <p>
                  <strong>E &nbsp;:&nbsp;</strong><asp:Label ID="lblEmail" runat="server"></asp:Label>
              </p>
          </div>
          <div class="row"  style="margin-top: -20px">
              <p>
                  <strong>W:&nbsp;</strong><p> www.france.com</p>
              </p>
          </div>
      </div> 
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-11"> 
            France<br/>
        </div> 
        <div class="col-xs-1">
            <img width="70" src="images/qr_code.png"/>    
        </div>       
    </div>
    <div>
        <img style="width: 400px" src="images/seritt.png"/>
    </div>
</div>
```